# How to add button in each row in list box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to add button in each row in ListBox XAML but I dont know how. Can anybody help me?
The code is below:

```
<ListBox Margin="5" DisplayMemberPath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding WindowsLicenseKeys}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKey}" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxNonScrollable}">
     <ListBox.InputBindings>
         <KeyBinding Gesture="Delete" Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveKeyCommand, ElementName=dg_keys}"/>
     </ListBox.InputBindings>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
<ListBox Margin="5" DisplayMemberPath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding WindowsLicenseKeys}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedKey}" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxNonScrollable}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>          
      <Button Content="Delete" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveKeyCommand, ElementName=dg_keys}"></Button>         
    </Grid>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```